# How can I inflate a custom view in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-custom-view

I'm trying to build a circle component and just getting weird errors.
When I use the component in the design mode I can see the circle component drawn to the view but I can't compile as I get the following errors.
All help welcomed. Thanks

```
// drawable/circle.xml
<Circle
        android:id="@+id/circle_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

// new package called Shapes.Circle.kt
import android.content.Context
import android.graphics.Canvas
import android.graphics.Color
import android.graphics.Paint
import android.graphics.PointF
import android.util.AttributeSet
import android.view.View

public class Circle @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null, defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : View(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {

    val paint = Paint().apply {
        color = Color.RED
    }

    private val centre = PointF(50F, 50F)

    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas?) {
        canvas?.drawCircle(centre.x, centre.y, 50F, paint)
    }
}
```

Here is my error:

```
021-01-12 04:12:03.354 28620-28620/com.example E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example, PID: 28620
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example/com.example.SplashScreen}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12 in com.example:layout/activity_splash_screen: Binary XML file line #12 in com.example:layout/activity_splash_screen: Error inflating class Circle
```

Comment: Please, post the activity_splash_screen.xml file content too it'd very helpful.

Comment: Look at the stack trace again. You may find some more text that tells more about the error.

Comment: Use fully qualified name for class in xml . `packagename.Circle` .

Comment: your error occured in line 12 in com.example:layout/activity_splash_screen file . please post com.example:layout/activity_splash_screen file .